# Changing video srcObject for MediaStream and Blob in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, html5-video, mediastream

I'm working on a WebRTC project and I need to replace two streams in a single video tag. I do it in two steps.

1. I'm adding the getUserMedia stream to the video tag.

   videoModalVideo.srcObject = stream; //user media stream
2. I record that stream with MediaRecorder and convert that into a Blob. I'm then trying to update the video src.

   videoModalVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob); //display that recorded stream

The problem is it's working fine in Chrome but not in Safari for iPhone.

I've read some resources and I tried with pause, load, and play methods on the video tag, but it's not working.

The issue is, I can only replace either src or srcObject. In the first step, I'm changing srcObject and in the second one, I'm changing src. That seems to create the issue.

When I tried to populate the stream again with srcObject (in the second step), it worked.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any development on this issue yet ?

Comment: No updates yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow that. The only solution is to keep two video tags and set the recorded source in the second one.